# JSP:Include not being called on forwarding page using doPost requestDispatcher

Tags: jsp, servlets, forward, jspinclude

I am currently writing an web application where you need to log in, using username and password. The next step in the process is to select a Project in which the logged in user is involved.

Once the project is selected and the submit button has been clicked, a servlet is called to prepare the selected project and create a `requestDispatcher` and `.forward` the req and resp to my mainpage.

The layout of the mainpage:
The header div:

```
<div><jsp:include page="header.do" flush="true"/></div>
```

The body div:

```
<div>   code that is present in the mainpage.jsp </div>
```

The footer div:

```
<div><jsp:include page="footer.do" flush="true"/></div>
```

Lets say that these 3 divs make up the mainpage.

After forwarding the page with the `requestDispatcher` I get to see the mainpage's content. However the `<jsp:include>`'s are not loaded (the DIV's are left empty). Only when I refresh the page (`doGet`, I assume) the includes will load correctly.

**Is there anyway to let the includes load on a doPost requestDispatch execution?**

**Note: The syntax of the requestDispatchers is exactly the same in the `doPost` and `doGet` methods.

If more clarification is needed, or extra code. Please let me know.

---

**EDIT**

*Servlet container used:*
Tomcat 6.0

*Web.xml:*

```
<!--- Servlet Mapping for Project Selection Servlet-->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ProjectSelect</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>MyProject.Login.ProjectSelect</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ProjectSelect</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ProjectSelect.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But what would the servlet mapping have to do with the `doGet` and `doPost`?

---

Kind regards,

B.

Comment: What servletcontainer are you using? How is the servlet on `*.do` configured in `web.xml`?

Comment: I mean, the servlet which is listening on `header.do` and `footer.do`. The `*.do` is a typical Struts dispatcher servlet URL pattern. As far it sounds like that the servlet is restricted to GET requests only by its configuration in `web.xml`.

Comment: Indeed. The Header.do and Footer.do are both java classes where in the  `doGet` method the code is processed and printed. The `doPost` method is empty. Furthermore the `header.do` and the `footer.do` are configured in the same way as the ProjectSelect servletmapping mentioned in the code above. Do I need to call `doGet(req, res)` in the doPost methods of both these servlets (`Header.do` and `footer.do`)?

Comment: That indeed did the job BalusC. Calling `doGet(request, response)` in the `doPost()` method did the job. Thank you very much for this insight. Question remains (to also help other people that might have run into this problem): Why is the `doPost()` method called when a <jsp:include> is called from another jsp page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it looked like that the servlet which is listening on `header.do` and `footer.do` is restricted to `GET` requests only. You need to ensure that it is to be executed on `POST` requests as well.

As to the new question in the comment:

> Why is the `doPost()` method called when a `<jsp:include>` is called from another jsp page?

Because the method of the HTTP request as fired by the client accounts. The `RequestDispatcher` doesn't fire a brand new HTTP request or so (it's only the `sendRedirect()` who is doing that). The `RequestDispatcher` just *reuses* the initial request for the included/forwarded resources. The request method won't be changed and remains in this case `POST` in the included/forwarded resources.

---

That said, you'd probably like to redesign/refactor all your `*.do` servlets to a single central front controller servlet which has the necessary logic implemented in `service()` method to avoid duplicated/boilerplate clutter. Or even better, adopt a MVC framework like JSF, Struts(2), Spring-MVC, etc. For more detail, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications/).

Comment: Much appreciated. Thank you very much. If you ever need help in bioinformatics (my field) do let me know :)

Comment: You're welcome. I don't think so, I've a B.Sc in biomedical technologies which is similar. I'll however keep it in mind ;)